# Is there a public transport search website for Belgium?

Tags: public-transport, planning, belgium

I would like to plan a couple of visits in Belgium to some remote places (not served by train). And I was wondering if there is a public transport planner.
I know google maps provides such a service but it depends on operators publishing their schedules.
I was wondering if there is such thing, at national scale, like there is in The Netherlands with 9292.nl .

Answer (score 11):

The [NMBS/SNCB journey planner](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/Default.aspx) knows about local transport, including bus lines. I'm not sure they always have information on service disruption or changes on short notices, so also check with the local bus operator, [De Lijn](https://www.delijn.be/en/), [TEC](https://www.infotec.be/index.aspx?language=en), or [STIB](http://www.stib-mivb.be/index.htm?l=en).

[image: example search]

Comment: That is a great tip, but it's good to keep in mind, at least from my trials, that the system always privileges the train even if more convenient bus alternatives exists.

Comment: @nsn Even when taking a bus would be faster? Unfortunately I don't know an alternative.

Comment: that was already a big help. Thanks!! I can't tell for sure, but I have that felling. I simulated a couple of routes, to some village near Hasselt, where there would be direct buses to Hasselt and the system always sent me by train.

Comment: @nsn Have you tried choosing "show also connections with longer travel time" in the advanced options?

Comment: no, that I didn't